What should I use instead of dependency injection in React to make part of my code interchangeable?
I'm learning React and I can't wrap my head around how can I accomplish loose coupling in my code. Here is a problem I'm trying to solve:
I'm creating a note taking app that is meant to store notes somewhere. For now it is user's filesystem, but I want to let user save his data in the cloud instead. So the code needs to be easily interchangeable. For now save() method should mean "save a file", sometime in the future can mean "save to Internet".
I have an OOP background so natural way of solving this problem is to:

Create interface called IStorageService having loadNote() and saveNote() methods
Implement this interface for both of storage targets (filesystem and REST API).

Now, React does not have dependency injection like e.g. Angular do. So I cannot just "inject" my class to any component. So I've ended up using Context API and "provider" component:
export function DataStorageProvider({ children }: Props) {
    const [storageReady, setStorageReady] = useState<boolean>(false);

    const [fileSystemStorage] = useState<IStorageService>(new FileSystemStorage());

    useEffect(() => {
        fileSystemStorage.registerOnChangeCallback((newState) => {
            setStorageReady(newState);
        });

        return () => {
            fileSystemStorage.registerOnChangeCallback(() => { });
        };
    }, [fileSystemStorage]);

    return (
        <DataStorageContext.Provider
            value={{
                storageReady,
                fileSystemStorage
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </DataStorageContext.Provider>
    );
}

Then I wrap my App inside <DataStorageProvider>:
function App() {

  return (
    <>
      <DataStorageProvider>
            <NoteDisplay></NoteDisplay>
      </DataStorageProvider>
    </>
  )
}

And I use useContext to get data storage in any component I want:
const dataStorage = useContext(DataStorageContext);

And every time I want to make an operation on a note I call: dataStorage?.fileSystemStorage.doSth().
Let's say it works, but now I need to implement another layer of business logic. Notes need to be processed before saving depending on their purpose, so I need to create ArchivedNote and ActiveNote classes that should have IStorageService injected.
What is a correct way of implementing these? Should I add more "states" to DataStorageProvider and pass IStorageService to them like that:
export function DataStorageProvider({ children }: Props) {
    const [storageReady, setStorageReady] = useState<boolean>(false);

    const [fileSystemStorage] = useState<IStorageService>(new FileSystemStorage());
    const [archivedNoteHandler] = useState<IArchivedNoteHandler>(new ArchivedNoteHandler(fileSystemStorage));
    const [activeNoteHandler] = useState<IActiveNoteHandler>(new ActiveNoteHandler(fileSystemStorage));
    [...]


Is it a correct way of doing this? I'm sceptical, because now all my services are independent states and if fileSystemStorage changes for some reason, all my other classes won't get updated... so I need to useEffect to recreate them then?

Are you using context for state management. If yes, you can possibly use useReducer hook in combination with it. Otherwise you can look into redux possibly where all your data will be stored and fetched for your app lifecycle. context is good if the data is not that much but at some point it will be overwhelming

can you give an example of how would you use useReducer? One reducer per starage action (load/save)?

I’d say there are multiple ways to do this, and it’s somewhat a matter of preference. You don’t need to use state for values that won’t change, however. You can declare them using ordinary const.

@TimMoore I declared them as const at first, but then I discovered that multiple instances of this class were created (I need it to be a singleton). Component I'm creating it in seem to be rerendering for some reason

You can declare consts outside a component if you want them to be singletons

I'm using (and developing) react-obsidian - a dependency injection library for React and React Native. It lets you write fully decoupled code without needing to use the UI as a "dependency container" (context and providers).
The API should be familiar to you if you're experienced with other DI frameworks. The gist is the dependencies are organized and instantiated in graphs:
@Singleton() @Graph()
class ApplicationGraph extends ObjectGraph {
  @Provides()
  httpClient(): HttpClient {
    return new HttpClient();
  }

  @Provides()
  biLogger(httpClient: HttpClient): BiLogger {
    return new BiLogger(httpClient);
  }
}

Then you can inject hooks, components, or classes. Here's how hooks are injected:
type Injected = DependenciesOf<ApplicationGraph, 'biLogger'>; // { biLogger: BiLogger }

// We must use destructuring for Obsidian to be able to inject the dependencies
const useButtonClick = ({ biLogger }: Injected) => {
  const onClick = useCallback(() => {
    biLogger.logButtonClick();
  }, [biLogger]);
  
  return { onClick };
};

// Export the injected hook
export default injectHook(useButtonClick, ApplicationGraph);

